# How to insert link, with lightbox, that opens specific page content only

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, javascript, the-content

I need insert link next to Woocommerce product addon label, that sould act as pop-up on clic, and open content of one specific page.
I have successfully done it by js and hardcoded url. 
But:

- Pop up loads whole page (header, footer, sidebars etc), I need only
  page content, ideally keeping istself page template.
- Not hadcoded url.

  `$(function () {
      $('<a class="venobox tips" data-vbtype="iframe" href="http://www.example.cz/cs/product-one/">Tips</a>').appendTo('.product-addon-product-one label');
  });`

Answer (score 0):

if you load page with iframe , then whole header , footer all will display in iframe ,

you can do 1 thing , using css hide header , footer and sidebar like below :
replace "#secondary" with your sidebar div id.

```
<style>
header{ display:none;}
footer { display:none;}
#secondary{ display:none;}
</style>
```

it worked for me.
thanks

Comment: Thanks you, but I would like to have "proper" solution, than css.